# Mover projeto do Assembla para Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, .net, team-foundation-server

O Assembla mudou os preços este ano e não vai ser sustentável continuar com o serviço. Há alguma maneira de migrar os projetos para o Visual Studio Team Services sem grandes complicações? Que procedimento devo fazer?

Comment: Somente o git ou você utiliza algum outro recurso?

Comment: estamos usando svn. Não há problema em migrar somente os ficheiros nas suas últimas versões.